# When should I denormalise data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm building a multi-currency application.

Consider a post table with the following fields:

```
id, country_id, price
```

Every time I fetch the price field, I also need the currency to display it on the front-end. Therefore, I need to do two joins (or run 3 queries with laravel `with`) every time I try and get the post just to get the currency.

```
post->country->currency
```

To solve this, I could just store the currency in the post table. This, however, goes against normalisation guidelines. It also duplicates data across tables.

Should I denormalise the data and store the currency in the post table?

Comment: What are your table columns exactly? What are your FDs? Without this we cannot discuss normalization or denormalization. Anyway normalization just eliminates update anomalies & complexity, which denormalization reintroduces. As in all optimization/engineering tradeoffs, you need to estimate/measure given your own circumstances. The alternative to 5NF--as you should know--is to manage updates & constraints properly--however you are willing to do that. How do you expect us to choose between these two options for you? (Even if you gave details of how you handled the denormalized case.)

Comment: @philipxy thanks! This is more of a hypothetical question; I can't post company code or change database structure just yet but was wondering what to do in such situations...

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

Should the `price` be frozen at the time of the sale?  (I think so.)  Don't normalize.

Or do you need to convert the price based on the current exchange rate?  Do normalize.

Also, `country_id` is not the proper key for `currency`.  The `currency_id` should be determined at the point of posting; keep the `country_id` if you need that also.

Then, when a currency is devalued, or a country moves to Euros, or ..., the schema does not  get in your way.

Also, there are cases where a tourist area is quite willing to take cash in different currencies.  Many magazines in the US list the price in both USD and Canadian Dollars.

Normalization purposes:

- Some "name" or "address" is likely to change in the future.  So normalize it into another table.  Otherwise, when the change occurs, you need to run around to multiple rows in multiple tables to effect the change.
- Saving space...  You have a string that occurs frequently, but (let's say) is unlikely to ever change.  By 'normalizing' (wrong term, but similar implementation), you can have the long string in only one place.  It is replaced by, say, a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` allowing up to 65K distinct values.  Caution:  If the string is short, such as the standard 2-letter country_codes, don't bother normalizing.  A 5-char zipcode is hardly worth shrinking to a 2-byte smallint.  currency codes have a nice standard (USD, EUR -- only 3 letters), too short to bother normalizing.

So, normalize if either of those applies.  In my experience, "price" does not fall into either category.  And

Comment: Great points. I just ran into another case where I have a table with books, and each page of a book can have a note. Normalized, I'd have to have a table containing a row for each page of the book (400+) that is then linked to a third table containing the notes, which while it would be normalised, seems excessive... Any ideas on how this looks in terms of performance long term?

Comment: @Michał I added to my Answer.  Perhaps my main grumble is your equating a "country" with a "currency".  A price is in a currency, _not_ a country.  If you want to sell the same thing for a different price in different countries, then a price is associated with _two_ thing -- currency and sales location.  That still defies "country -> currency".

Comment: Hehe! My app is designed so that a sale can only occur at a specific university (face to face, no shipping), which belongs to a currency, which then belongs to a country ;) The DB is riddled with flaws that are currently being ironed out; my question is more of a hypothetical one, hence my other example in the comments ;)! Code & more on GitHub: https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr

Comment: Textbooks give a _theoretical_ answer to "when to normalize"; I give a _practical_ and a _performance_ view on the issue.